# Catia V5 macro to access axis-system inside a geometric set

Tags: vba, catia

[image]

Using a Catia V5 macro I want to save axis system and other geometric elements  inside a geometic set to a txt file. I'm able to access the geometric elements like points and lines but not the axis system(Shown in image) .

```
'Procedure to access the geometic elements inside a geometric set    
Dim prtDoc  As Part
Dim hbds As HybridBodies
Dim hbs As HybridShapes
Set hbs = hbds.GetItem(objSel.Item2(1).Value.Name).HybridShapes
```

To access a geometric element and get its type

```
MsgBox TypeName(hbs.Item(i))
```

But how to access the axis system?

Comment: I really don't think you are suposed to have an Axis System inside a geometrical set. Also, what is the selected element you have in your selection?

Comment: Selected element is a Geometrical Set. I want to export all the required data to a text file. Geometric set(CSYS) contains all the data I want as shown in figure.

Comment: My actual geometric set contains lines,  circles, arcs. I'm able to import all except local axis system.

Comment: Check out the answer I posted, see if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axis Systems can't be found inside a Geometrical Set by looping through child items via the CATIA API.
A `hybridBody` (Geometrical Set) only contains `HybridShapes`, `HybridBodies` and `Sketches`.

You can see `Lines`, `Points`, and such other items because they are all `HybridShapes`.

As far as I know, the only way of getting the Axis System object inside a Geometrical Set is through the `Selection.Search` method.

Assuming you have the CSYS Geometrical Set in your selection, you can do the following:

```
Dim Selection as INFITF.Selection
Dim AxisSystem as INFITF.AxisSystem
'Initialize Selection and other code here
Selection.Search("'Part Design'.'Axis System';sel")
for i = 1 to Selection.Count2
    set AxisSystem = Selection.Item2(i).Value
    '...
Next
```

Comment: Thank you AugustoQ. Now, I'm able to export the axis system data using search and selection.